# Knowing video graphic memory requirements without graphic card

Tags: hardware

I'm still using old hardware for rendering, I cannot render using my graphic card. I only have 4Gb of system ram. Right now blender say it just use about 4Gb while rendering, but in the task manager it is
just 2Gb in use and 12Gb to 17Gb commited (blender is the only apps running).

How do I know how much system ram and video ram do I need to render similar scene, for guidance to buy newer hardwares and graphic card in the future?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without knowing more about the scene you're trying to render. To advise you on system specs, it would also be helpful to know how much you use blender and for what. Generally, I'd say for present day, to give yourself enough overhead, and in order to stay relatively future proof, I would go with minimum 32gb system ram, plus a graphics card with a minimum of 8gb VRAM (though more is always better if you can afford it). This will equip you for moderate to moderate-heavy blender use.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.